# Chosen Plugin jQuery keep default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, default-value, jquery-chosen

I have a Request with the **Chosen Javascript** plugin : https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Is there a way to enable a default `option` value when you're looking for another one?

Let me explain, I have a selector in HTML where I have a lot of different options and the last one is *"Other"*, when it's selectionned, I want to show an `input` text to let the user add a **new choice** if he wants.

So I would like to let appear everytime the **"Other"** option when an user is looking for an *((un)existing)* option, but with this plugin I didn't fhind the way to make it.

Let me give you an exemple :

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "220px"});

$(".chosen-select").chosen().change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
    $('div#newcolor').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('div#newcolor').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<select class="chosen-select" name="test">
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="purple">Purple</option>
  <option value="">Ohter</option>
</select>
<div id="newcolor" class="hide">
  <label>You can add a new color : </label>
  <input value="" placeholde="Try with Pink">
</div>
<hr>
<button>Submit</button>
```

So if you try to look for Pink, you could not select "Other" option and so you can't add one new...
Thanks

Comment: Hi! Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @msanford I edited my question with a snippet to let you know what is the feature I'm looking for. Thanks